# How to convert sqlite data into xml file and xml file into sql data?

Tags: iphone

I am developing an application. In that I want to create an XML file with sqlite data and place another XML data into sqlite field. So please tell me how to do this.

Comment: This question amounts to, "Please write my program for me". That's not an answerable or reasonable question.

Answer (score 0):

Well hope you used Core Data to interact with your DB.
If you did so, just loop your Entities and use a NSMutableString to build your XML document.

Comment: Is there any example for that.Because i dont know how to use the core data.