# How to convert the sqlite data into xml form?

Tags: iphone

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert sqlite data into xml file and xml file into sql data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046280/how-to-convert-sqlite-data-into-xml-file-and-xml-file-into-sql-data)

iam developing one applciation.In that i need to convert the sqlite data into xml form.SO please tell me how to do this one?